# How to make Jtable show only certain number of rows?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have 1000 rows to sort in Jtable. After sorting , I only care about first 50 rows and don't want to show other rows. Other questions' answer suggest using Model's setRowCount to limit the count,but doing so will unsort the table and I will never been able to sort by other condition using the whole dataset.

Comment: Add a filter (for the first 50 rows) to the row sorter...

Comment: Wow，how dumb am I. Thank you！